# Error in dictionary to list manipulation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got stuck in a code in python. I am new to python.
I have tried to add the polynomial in a basic way but I don't know how to get the values as a dictionary and convert it to a list and back.
This is the code I have tried:

```
def add(s1,s2):
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        new = [i for i in s1]
        for i in range(len(s2)): new[i] += s2[i]
    else:
        new = [i for i in s2]
        for i in range(len(s1)): new[i] += s1[i]
    return new
```

When I run this program I got output as

```
add((2,0),(3,1)) [5,1]
```

but I gave input like this `add([(4,3),(3,0)],[(-4,3),(2,1)])`, which gives me an an error. How to get dictionaries as input for following code?
for example if I gave input as

```
addpoly([(4,3),(3,0)],[(-4,3),(2,1)]) it should give me 
[(2, 1),(3, 0)]
```

if there the output is zero it should return empty list[].

Comment: I don't see any dictionary in your example, that's a list of tuples?

Comment: The reason you get an error is that you're trying to do `(4,3) + (-4,3)`, which won't work. Do you want this to work recursively?

Comment: @DanielLee except that is not valid syntax for a dictionary. `{'key': (4, 3), ...}` is the correct way to build a dict.

Answer (score 2):

I am running your code in python-3.x and it gives output like `[(-4, 3, 4, 3), (2, 1, 3, 0)]`
so it is only a concatenation of the input, because for the input `add([(4,3),(3,0)],[(-4,3),(2,1)])` there is a list inside another list.

For more explanation: if the input is like `add([(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)],[(-1,-1),(-2,-2),(-3,-3)])` then the output is: [(**-1, -1**, 1, 1), (**-2, -2**, 2, 2), (**-3, -3**, 3, 3)]

And for adding two list elements code:

```
def add(s1,s2):
if len(s1) > len(s2):
    new = [i for i in s1]
    for i in range(len(s2)): 
        if(isinstance(new[i], int)):
            new[i] += s2[i]
        else:
            t1 = new[i][0] + s2[i][0]
            t2 = new[i][1] + s2[i][1]
            new[i] = (t1,t2)
else:
    new = [i for i in s2]
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if(isinstance(new[i], int)):
             new[i] += s1[i]
        else:
            t1 = new[i][0] + s1[i][0]
            t2 = new[i][1] + s1[i][1]
            new[i] = (t1,t2)
return new
```

If we give input:

```
print(add([(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)],[(-1,-1),(-2,-2),(-3,-3)]))
print(add((2,0),(3,1)))
print(add([(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)],[(-1,-1),(-2,-2)]))
```

we get the output:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
[5, 1]
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (3, 3)]
```